# Basic Objective-C syntax: "%@"?

Tags: c, objective-c, syntax

I'm working through the Stanford iPhone podcasts and have some basic questions.

The first: why is there no easy string concatenation? (or am I just missing it?)

I needed help with the NSLog below, and have no idea what it's currently doing (the %@ part). Do you just substitute those in wherever you need concatenation, and then comma separate the values at the end?

```
NSString *path = @"~";
NSString *absolutePath = [path stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

NSLog(@"My home folder is at '%@'", absolutePath);
```

whereas with any other programing language I'd have done it like this:

```
NSLog(@"My home folder is at " + absolutePath);
```

Thanks! (Additionally, any good guides/references for someone familiar with Java/C#/etc style syntax transitioning to Objective-C?)

Comment: why is there no easy string concatenation? `[@"foo" stringByAppendingString:@"bar"]`.  Yes, really.  You can also look at the docs for `NSMutableString` which helps a little.

Comment: Do you really think that's "easy" compared to "foo" + "bar"? But is that a better way to do it than the '%@' approach I took?

Comment: `stringByAppendingString` makes the intent much clearer than overloading `+`. Or is it `.` to concatenate? In that respect it's easier than using the wrong overloaded operator. Besides, what should happen if you attempt to append an integer to a string? E.g. `"foo" + 6`. What about appending a string to an integer? Using `stringByAppendingString` means I don't have to think about it. Perhaps you don't mean *easier* so much as *lazier*.

Comment: stringByAppendingString also make it more clear that strings are immutable, it's very easy to use "+" or "." many many times in a single block of code, and remain blissfully unaware of the number of objects you are creating.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`%@` is a placeholder in a format string, for a NSString instance.

When you do something like:

```
NSLog(@"My home folder is at '%@'", absolutePath);
```

You are telling NSLog to replace the `%@` placeholder with the string called absolutePath.

Likewise, if you put more placeholders, you can specify more values to replace those placeholders like this:

```
NSString *absolutePath = @"/home/whatever";
NSLog(@"My home #%d folder is at '%@'", 5, absolutePath);
```

Will print:

> My home #5 is at /home/whatever

An easy way to do string concatenation:

```
NSString *s1 = @"Hello, ";
NSString *s2 = @"world.";
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", s1, s2];
// s will be "Hello, world."
```

You can't have a `+` sign as a string concatenate operator, since there is no operator overloading in Objective-C.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clear and simple explanation. For my example, would it be better ("more objective-C-like") to do it via a placeholder or via string concatenation?

Comment: String format specifiers can print other types apart from Objective-C objects, such as integers (`%i`), doubles (`%f`), C strings (`%s`) and so on. You can't do this with the concatenation operators. String format specifiers come from C, and are used in functions like `printf()` for output. The `%@` syntax is an Objective-C addition to the existing C string format specifiers which prints the output of the `-description` method of an Objective-C object.

Comment: I would personally use placeholders. But it is not wrong if you do it with string concatenation... :-)

Answer (score 4):

That is a [string format specifier](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).  Basically it allows you to specify a placeholder in the string and the values that are to be inserted into the placeholder's spot.  The link I reference above lists the different notations for the placeholders and each placeholder's specific format.

It's just like C#'s `String.Format` method:

```
NSLog(String.Format("My home folder is at '{0}'", absolutePath));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NSString +stringWithFormat](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithFormat_) to do concatenation:

```
NSString* a = // ...
NSString* b = // ...
NSString* a_concatenated_with_b = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",a,b];
```

The reason for the "%@" is that the string formatting is based off of and extends the [printf format strings syntax](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html). These functions take a variable number of arguments, and anything beginning with a percent sign (%) is interpreted as a place holder. The subsequent characters determine the type of the place holder. The standard printf does not use "%@", and since "@" is the symbol commonly used for things that Objective-C adds to the C language, it makes sense that the "@" would symbolize "an Objective-C object".

There is no automatic concatentation using the plus sign (+), because NSString* is a pointer type, and Objective-C is a strict superset of C, and so, consequently, adding to an NSString* object does pointer  manipulation. Objective-C does not have any operator overloading feature as in the C++ language.

Answer (score 0):

Also, `%@` is fairly versatile, as it actually inserts the result of the argument's description method into the result string. For NSString, that's the string's value, other classes can provide useful overrides. Similar to toString in Java, for example.