# Beautify NSLog of NSArray & NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm dealing with deeply nested NSArray's and NSDictionary's and it's very time consuming to say the least. [data objectatindex:0] valueForKey:@"blah"] etc etc

Does anyone know of a nice iOS category to recursively log the structure, highlight the type and show the values?

Might be asking a bit much but you never know :)

Comment: Similar to the way plists are displayed in XCode? Is this to be displayed on the device or is it just for you to use?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
for (id key in dictionary) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@ \n", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

but i can't think of any nice way of getting the output beautiful except copy & paste it into a [jsonFormatter](http://www.bodurov.com/JsonFormatter/) (for example)

**EDIT**: @Andrey Starodubtsev has the solution for XCode > 5.x below:

```
NSLog( @"%@", dictionaryYouWantToPrint );
```

Comment: Care to describe how that (passing the object to `NSLog()` with the `%@` specifier) works?

Comment: @Droppy you mean this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634099/basic-objective-c-syntax

Answer (score 136):

Hmm. Simple

```
NSLog( @"%@", dictionaryYouWantToPrint );
```

outputs following result for me:

```
{
    id = 1;
    matchCount = 0;
    matchPattern = abcdef;
    number = "123456";
    sessionID = 5;
    status = Unknown;
    timerStart = 1367229348;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use block after iOS5, like

```
[anArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog (@"object->%@",object);
}];

[aDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop){
    NSLog(@"key->%@, value-> %@",key,object);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

This will print in console without NSLog.

During debugging, when your breakpoint is below your dictionary, you can type in console

```
NSDictionary * myDict = ...;
```

> po myDict

and you will get printed dictionary in console.

You can even cast objects to another types in console:

[image]